# Getting all custom post taxonomies and exhibiting only part of them

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have a custom post type, that has several taxonomies.

For each one, I need to show something like:

```
Taxonomy name: Taxonomy value
```

So, since I have posts that have the following taxonomy tree:

```
Categories -> Bikes

Bikes Models -> Model 1

Bikes Brands -> Brand 1

Genre -> Male
```

I need to show all of them with the respective name and value.

I got all the post taxonomies, but I need to 'delete' part of it.

**This is my code:**

```
$args = array(
'post' => $post->ID,
'before' => '<p class="meta">',
'sep' => ' ',
'after' => '<p class="meta">',
'template' => '%s  %l<br/>',
);
```

**That produces:**

```
- Categorias | Acessório
- Tipos de Acessórios | Tipos de Acessórios 2
- Modelos de Acessórios | Modelos de Acessórios 3
- Marcas de Acessórios | Marca de Acessório 3
- Tamanhos | XL
- Gênero | Masculino
- Material Quadro | Carbono
- Extras |  Com garantia, Como novo, Dobrável, Dupla-Suspensão, Excelente estado, Exclui pedais, Exclui pneus, Exclui rodas, Pouco uso, Preço negociável, Sem selim e Tem amortecedor trás
```

*The thing is:*

1. I need to exclude some of those taxonomys (Categorias, Tipos de acessórios, Modelos de Acessórios, Marcas de Acessórios & Extras)
2. The ones I need to show, will ALWAYS BE DIFFERENT on each item. But the ones I need to exclude/hide WILL ALWAYS BE THE SAME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to do it with `get_the_taxonomies()`[Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_taxonomies/)
and `unset()` [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)

**So, here is how the final code looks like:**

```
//define the arguments so the output will have the format I want
$args = array(
    'template' => __( '%s: %l.' ), 
    'term_template' => '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>',
);
//get the array and store it
$taxList = get_the_taxonomies( $post->ID, $args );
//remove the categories I don't want based on their slug
unset($taxList['categorias']);
//Show the list without the ones specified above
print_r($taxList);
```